# randomString is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to create a function that generate me a random string or number.

My function in ts like this:

```
  randomString() {
    let chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    let string_length = 8;
    let randomstring = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
      let rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
      randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
    }
  }
```

Html code

```
    <form [formGroup]="addProductForm">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input formControlName="Line_num" type="button" value="Create Random String" onClick="randomString();">  
  <input type="text" name="Line_num" value="">    
            </div>
    <form>
```

When I click button , show this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: randomString is not defined  at TMLInputElement.onclick

Now, 
I change this,

```
this.addProductForm = this.fb.group({
    'Line_num': new FormControl(this.randomString(), Validators.required),
    });
```

In function

```
   randomString() { 
  return Math
    .random() // Create a random number
    .toString(36) // Convert it to string (26 letters + 10 numbers)
    .split('') // Creates an array of those letters
    .slice(-8) // Take the last height ones
    .join(''); // Join them back to create a string
}
```

Html code

```
 <form [formGroup]="addProductForm">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input type="text" formControlName="Line_num" name="Line_num">
</div>
</form>
```

The problem has been resolved

Comment: use `function` keyword while defining a function. `function randomString(){..}`

Comment: error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

Comment: Typescript code

Comment: At which line do you get above error?

Comment: I change this onClick="randomString(); in (click)="randomString();" and work. Now if you can help me, I want to display this randomstring  in  this  <input type="text" name="Line_num" value="">

Comment: Please, try to avoid editing a new question into a new one as it quickly renders old answers obsolete and not everyone is willing to keep updating his/her post to keep up with your current problem. Instead, please consider posting a new question.

Comment: Also worth considering, please edit your question to use only one of the two angular / angularjs tags, choosing the one that fits your problem. That is, assuming angular is related to your problem in the first place - at the moment I don't see an evident connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a simpler way of creating random strings ?

```
randomString() { 
  return Math
    .random() // Create a random number
    .toString(36) // Convert it to string (26 letters + 10 numbers)
    .split('') // Creates an array of those letters
    .slice(-8) // Take the last height ones
    .join(''); // Join them back to create a string
}
```

This is easier to read and would correct your issue.

For your edit :

```
this.addProductForm = this.fb.group({
  'Line_num': new FormControl(this.randomString(), Validators.required)
});
```

In your HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="addProductForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="Line_num" name="Line_num">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't like being ignored, but here you go.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ignore you. This too is a very good way. The problem is that it can not be displayed in html

Comment: Of course it can ... The issue isn't how the random is created, it is how you display it. Anyway, I told you how to give your input a value, by editing my question. tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you, the function work for me, but the display in html does not work. I edit my post

Comment: No problem, be sure to marke your question as resolved !

Answer (score 0):

To display your value in

`<input type="text" name="Line_num" value="">`

in Javascript you could do something like adding unique ID to your field like this

`<input id="myUniqueField" type="text" name="Line_num" value="">`

then at the end of randomString function just do

`document.getElementById("myUniqueField").value = randomstring;`